# Parsing Double in Mono (C#) fails

Tags: mono, hard-float

I need to serialize objects to JSON. If I install mono from apt-get, serializing with [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) does not work.

I added this line into **/etc/apt/sources.list**:

```
deb http://debian.meebey.net/experimental/mono /
```

After this, i ran

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

This version of mono supports serializing into JSON. If you dont add the line into ***sources.list***, all serializations will fail, not only those with double values. When I have a double in a dictionary or in a list, this exception always gets thrown thy JSON.net.

**Input string was not in the correct format**

Here is some sample code, so you can try (you need to add a reference to JSON.net):

```
try { Console.WriteLine(3.14159265359f.ToString()); } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
try { Console.WriteLine(3.14159265359d.ToString()); } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
try { Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("3.14159265359").ToString()); } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
try { Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("3,14159265359").ToString()); } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
try { Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(3.14159265359f)); } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
try { Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(3.14159265359d)); } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
try { Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<object>() { "test", DateTime.Now, 3.14159265359f, 3.14159265359d})); } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
try { Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<object, object>() {
    {"test", DateTime.Now},
    {DateTime.Now, 3.14159265359f},
    {3.14159265359f, 3.14159265359d},
    {3.14159265359d, "test"},
})); } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
```

In my case, this results in

```
3,141593
3,14159265359
314159265359
Input string was not in the correct format
Input string was not in the correct format
Input string was not in the correct format
Input string was not in the correct format
Input string was not in the correct format
```

I need to serialize and dictionary or an object where some properties are double numbers, but I dont know how to fix this error.

Comment: Try adding `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to your `ToDouble` conversions to see if they parse properly. i.e. `Convert.ToDouble("3.14159265359", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` and `Convert.ToDouble("3,14159265359",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: I dont need to convert a number with a comma (,) to a double. I need to serialize objects with JSON.net. JSON.net throws the same exception when a double is in my object. The third line of my result shows that parsing a double is working.

Comment: The value of the third line is incorrect.

Comment: What happens if you try to serialize a variable of type double?

Comment: You mean the 6th line?
`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(3.14159265359d)`

Comment: Yes,  third line of output

Comment: The third line shows the output of parsing a string to a double. The comma is missing. `314159265359` The sixth line shows the ouput when I serialize a double to JSON (string). This throws an exception. `Input string was not in the correct format`. That is my problem. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Does the serialize work if you use a variable of type double?

Comment: NO! You can see the commands in my first code box and the result of each command in the second box. As you can see every command after the third results in the same exception! That's my problem.

Comment: I'm saying just trying this ` SerializeObject(variableOfTypeDouble)`

Comment: What does your `mono --version` display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me on my Pi.  I'm using a version of Mono that I compiled back in December before the patch for hard-float and Mono was released.  Here's the output I get.  I suspect that the issue has to do with the internationalization of the decimal point character.

Here is the output of `mono --version`:

```
Mono Runtime Engine version 3.2.7 (master/e42840f Thu Dec  5 11:31:03 EST 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2013 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

I also manually downloaded Json.net and specifically referenced the NET20 dll.

```
johnma@raspberrypi ~/tpf$ $ mcs -r:Newtonsoft.Json.dll jsontest.cs
johnma@raspberrypi ~/tpf$ $ ./jsontest.exe
NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = .
3.141593
3.14159265359
3.14159265359
314159265359
3.14159274
3.14159265359
["test","2014-04-11T16:32:29.975495-04:00",3.14159274,3.14159265359]
{"test":"2014-04-11T16:32:30.971131-04:00","00/735334/0001 16:32:30":3.14159274,"3.141593":3.14159265359,"3.14159265359":"test"}
```

**Update: Success! I've recreated your problem!**

I get your results when I run `jsontest.exe` using LANG=de_DE.UTF-8, see below:

```
johnma@raspberrypi ~/tpf$ $ LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 ./jsontest.exe
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = de-DE
NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ,
3,141593
3,14159265359
314159265359
Input string was not in the correct format
Input string was not in the correct format
Input string was not in the correct format
Input string was not in the correct format
Input string was not in the correct format
```

I suspect that this is most likely a bug or quirk in Mono.  Clearly `Convert.ToDouble("3,14159265359")` is throwing an exception.  I suspect that all other exceptions are due to the Double values being stored internally as String objects.

Can you run your exe using `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`?

Here's the source I compiled:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = "
                           + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture );
        NumberFormatInfo nfi = NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        Console.WriteLine( "NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = "
                           + nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator );
        try { Console.WriteLine(3.14159265359f.ToString()); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        try { Console.WriteLine(3.14159265359d.ToString()); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        try { Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("3.14159265359").ToString()); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        try { Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("3,14159265359").ToString()); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        try { Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(3.14159265359f)); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        try { Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(3.14159265359d)); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        try { Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<object>() {
            "test", DateTime.Now, 3.14159265359f, 3.14159265359d})); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        try { Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<object, object>() {
            {"test", DateTime.Now},
            {DateTime.Now, 3.14159265359f},
            {3.14159265359f, 3.14159265359d},
            {3.14159265359d, "test"},
        })); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
    }
}
```

**Updated to add code to display NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator**

Comment: Can you give me instructions on how to compile mono like you did?

Comment: I don't think it's my version, I think it's our system's localization differences.  What does NumberDecimalSeparator display on your system?

Comment: I can't connect to this site right now, but these are the instructions I used: http://mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono

Comment: Wait, do you mean it doesnt work because we have different region settings? Why does `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(3.14159265359f)` throw an exception? There is nothing to convert (from a string)!